# Returning Raw Json in ElasticSearch NEST query

Tags: elasticsearch, servicestack, json.net, nest

I'm doing a small research about a client for elastic search in .net and I found that NEST is one of the most supported solutions for this matter.

I was looking at Nest's docummentation and I couldn´t find a way to output a raw json from a query and avoid the serialization into an object, because I'm using angularJs in the front end I don´t want to overload the process of sending the information to the client with some unnecessary steps.

......and also  I'd like to know how can I overrdide the serialization process?

I found that NEST uses Json.NET which I would like to change for the servicestack json serielizer.

thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hi Pedro you can do this with NEST

```cs
var searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<ElasticSearchProject>()
    .Query(q=>q.MatchAll());
var request = this._client.Serializer.Serialize(searchDescriptor);
ConnectionStatus result = this._client.Raw.SearchPost(request);
Assert.NotNull(result);
Assert.True(result.Success);
Assert.IsNotEmpty(result.Result);
```

This allows you to strongly type your queries, but return the string `.Result` which is the raw response from elasticsearch as string to your

`request` can be an object or the string so if you are OK with the internal json serialize just pass searchDescriptor directly

Comment: thanks is there any way to replace the json.net serializer impl with a custom one? (let's say servicestack)

Comment: @Martijn Is there a way to visualize the query being sent before it is sent?

Comment: result.Result does not seem to exist in current API. How is this now achieved? I want to pass through the elasticsearch server response directly to my client, as the client uses a javascript library to work with standard ES responses for faceting etc.  thanks.

Comment: I have errors on ConnectionStatus  and SearchPost. Am I missing a namespace?

Comment: This code seems completely broken when using a newer version (2.4) of ElasticClient.

Comment: If you're returning the raw response of ES, NEST doesn't serialize it or need to. It is in the JSON format the Java based ES server serialized it in.

Answer (score 0):

Use RequestResponseSerializer instead of Serializer.

```
var searchDescriptor = ...;
...
byte[] b = new byte[60000];
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b))
{
    this._client.RequestResponseSerializer.Serialize(searchDescriptor , ms);
}
var rawJson = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b);
```